# why is 'c' printed before anything else in code sample below?

Tags: python

```
def f(): 
    print("f")
class C: 
    print("c")

    def __init__(self): 
        print('i')  
    def m(self): 
        print('m')
f()
C().m()
```

I expect that since f() is called first, the output should start with f but the output is 'cfim'

Comment: Because you `print('c')`during *definition of `C`*.

Comment: `f` isn't called first, you need to define your class first, as your output is showing

Comment: @deceze let assume I am only using f() the output is still 'cf'. I thought since the function f is outside the class definition code block,  f() should only output 'f'

Comment: `class` definitions in Python are *regular Python code*. Everything inside the `class` block gets executed as Python code. The `def` statements define functions, which later become methods of the class, and the `print` statement… well… prints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C is printed first because the print function execute during the creation of the class itself.  Print('c') will be executed in the same way a class attribute will be set during the class definition.

Answer (score 0):

A Function gets executed only when it is called. However, the class will be processed in the beginning (order-wise) and so the print statement inside the class will get executed